# Azure Data factory to add additional rows in csv based on multiple values in a column

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an excel file in an Azure blob that I convert into csv file and perform some transformations also on that file. The excel file is a list of Product values for that day. So the columns are like Data, Product names, Value. The product names are a list of different products separated by space.

How do I denormalize this dataset where each product name is expanded into a separate row.
Example this table below

```
Date | Products | Value
20-02-2019 | prod_1 prod_2 prod_3 | 43
20-02-2019 | prod_4 | 32
21-02-2019 | prod_1 prod_4 | 32
21-02-2019 | prod_2 | 40
```

should transform as

```
Date | Product | Values
20-02-2019 | prod_1 | 43
20-02-2019 | prod_2 | 43
20-02-2019 | prod_3 | 43
20-02-2019 | prod_4 | 32
21-02-2019 | prod_1 | 32
21-02-2019 | prod_4 | 32
21-02-2019 | prod_2 | 40
```

I've looked into mapping data flow and alter rows but they both need a database as a sink. I'm relatively new to ADF so wondering if there's a way to do such that the transformation is stored in a blob?

Comment: Is this actually an Excel file or pipe-delimited as per your sample data?

Comment: The actual file is an excel file. I'm just showing here how the data in the file will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the solution and double  clicking on what @Mark Kromer MSFT said . I was able to achieve this by using the
Derived column - I splited the Products column on space ' ' . This gave an array with the poduct names . I used the flatten activity to Unroll by products . and then I used the Filter activity ( in youe dataset you have a space between the the pipe and the product name ( eg ) | prod_1. The below animation will make the implementation more clear .

[image]

Comment: Oh this is extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in ADF data flows and sink it to a blob folder. Alter Row is only needed if you are performing update/delete/upsert operations.